# lambda retrieve integer from map

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8

I am trying to get the number after doing calculations using Lambda expression, but getting the error.

The lambda expression I am using:

```
int num = Optional.ofNullable(list.stream().filter(x->x.getType().getTypeId()==Type.getTypeId()).limit(1).map(x->x.getNum())).get();
```

After filtering, I want to get the first retrieved value. But I am getting the error as

```
cannot convert from Stream<Integer> to int
```

So, currently the way I am using is

```
Optional<> li = list.stream().filter(x->x.getType().getTypeId()==Type.getTypeId()).findFirst();
if (li.isPresent()) {
    num = li.map(x-> x.getNum()).get();
}
```

But, I was looking if the above could be done in a single line rather than extra `if` statement

Earlier, I tried the `get()` with `findFirst()`, but it was giving `nullpointerException`. How can I safely retrieve the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`list.stream().filter(x->x.getType().getTypeId()==Type.getTypeId()).limit(1).map(x->x.getNum())` returns a `Stream`. You are lacking the `findFirst` terminal operation:

```
int num = 
    list.stream()
        .filter(x->x.getType().getTypeId()==Type.getTypeId())
        .map(x->x.getNum())
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(0); // default value in case the Stream is empty after the filtering
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I got what I was missing. It looks NPE safe as well.